# Fragment to Activity back again on same Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity with 4 fragments. on fragment 3 there is a button when i click on that button i go to some other activity(Like TestActivity). I use this code to go from fragment 3 to that TestActivity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), TestActivity.class));
```

When i press back button on TestActivity it redirect me to the 1st Fragment(Default) of Main Activity.  I want that when user press back on TestActivity to again come to Fragment 3. Please suggest me how i achieve this behaviour. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should know it has difference between `fragment` and `activity` back stack.

In change your `fragment` you should use add  `addToBackStack("name")` , something like this :

**KOTLIN :**

**In `fragment` :**

```
 requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.framelayout_main_fragmentContainer,SecondFragment())
        .addToBackStack("first")
        .commit()
```

**In `activity` :**

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.framelayout_main_fragmentContainer,Firstfragment())
        .addToBackStack("first")
        .commit()
```

**JAVA :**

```
         getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
         replace(R.id.framelayout_main_fragmentContainer, Firstfragment()).
         addToBackStack("first").commit();
```